# How to retrieve the onboard ethernet MAC address of a computer?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, .net-4.5, ethernet

I am trying to retrieve the MAC address for the onboard ethernet adapter from a computer, in order to generate a unique identifier for the device. Below is the approach I am using.

```
NetworkInterface[] ifConfig = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
int maxHash = int.MinValue;
Guid D = Guid.Empty;

foreach (NetworkInterface net in ifConfig)
{
    if (net.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
    {
                if (maxHash < net.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString().GetHashCode())
                {
                    maxHash = net.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString().GetHashCode();

                    ID = new Guid(String.Concat("00000000-0000-0000-0000-", net.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()));

                }
    }
}
```

However, the Bluetooth adapter, VM adapter and several other network adapters are also of the `NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet` type. How can I specifically get the onboard ethernet connection's MAC address?

Doing a contains to omit those wouldn't be possible. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Mainly because MAC addresses are NOT unique. This gets even worse if you consider (cloned) virtual machines. See https://superuser.com/a/968346

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, it is nonetheless the de-facto industry standard approach, as used by, e.g., FlexLM.  What's the alternative?

Comment: @HarryJohnston as I said you can just generate a Guid and use that. You can do that clientside since the chance of collision in reality is non-existant. You can't use anything hardware side to identify a computer. One reason are virtual machines, another are modifications to the computer like swapping a network card or adding a GPU. Changing (defect) hardware would change the ID of that computer.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, *typically*, the goal is to generate an ID that stays the same even if the software is removed and reinstalled, or if the operating system is removed and reinstalled, so a GUID won't work.  It is often also desirable to be able to predict the ID in advance of installing the software.  But the OP didn't actually specify what their requirements are, so I suppose either interpretation is valid.

Comment: If you query WMI with `AdapterType=Ethernet 802.3` you only get real Ethernet NICs.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a Powershell Script to generate a permanent system-format-immutable unique ID for a Windows PC for **inventory purposes** (QR encode the ID, print it on a sticker...).

It concatenates the PC manufacturer UUID field with the permanent MAC address of every PCI-connected network adapter (sorted alphabetically by MAC). The PCI requirement automatically dismisses removable or virtual NICs. The real script MD5-hashes the resulting string in order to obtain a more homogeneous identifier (constant length and 0-9A-F set of symbols), but I will omit this here for the sake of simplicity

I could’ve settled for the PC manufacturer UUID and call it a day, but I didn’t feel comfortable with an ID that relies on:

- Each PC manufacturer in the world making the effort of filling in the UUID BIOS field.
- Every PC manufacturer making the effort of keeping track of already used UUIDs

Basically, I tried to adhere to the intuitive idea of putting in the mixer as many non-removable components with permanent and “unique” (dream on) identifier as possible.

This ID generation technique is not fail proof: if a new PCI network adapter is added to the system, the ID will change. But with the popularization of integrated NICs I believe this is no longer something to worry about, if it ever was.

This solution is not directly applicable for C#, but I believe it can be easily adapted since Powershell shares almost the same .net object-class ecosystem.

```
#Variable names in spanish, but if I try to translate them in a hurry
#I will most certainly end up with a non-working script

$elpc=(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct)
$id=$elpc.UUID #This is the UUID the manufacturer wrote somewhere in the BIOS

#Get network devices
#"Net" for network devices, "PCI*" because PCI connected devices begin that way
$dispositivosdered=@(Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {($_.Class -eq "Net") -and ($_.InstanceId -like "PCI*")})

#Get network adapters
#Use "PermanentAddress" property. "MacAddress" property can be spoofed easily
$tarjetasdered=@(Get-Netadapter | Sort-Object PermanentAddress)

#Double loop to rule out any network adapters which are not PCI
#Comparison is made using long name, ie "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2"
#Is the only valid field I found to (inner) join the device and adapter worlds
for($j=0; $j -lt $tarjetasdered.length; $j++) {
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $dispositivosdered.length; $i++) {
        if($dispositivosdered[$i].FriendlyName -eq $tarjetasdered[$j].InterfaceDescription) {
            if(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($tarjetasdered[$j].PermanentAddress)) {
                $id= $id + $tarjetasdered[$j].PermanentAddress.Replace("-", "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an option (not the best, but still =) ) - You can try to use
metric. In most cases the metric of the network to a physical network
card priority

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.ComponentModel;
            using System.Data;
            using System.Drawing;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Management;
            using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            using System.Windows.Forms;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
                ManagementObjectSearcher query = new
                 ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = 'TRUE'");
                ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = query.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
                {
                    if (!(mo["Description"].ToString().Contains("VM")))
                    {
                        if (!(mo["Description"].ToString().Contains("Virtual")))
                        {
                            if (!(mo["Description"].ToString().Contains("Hyper")))
                            {
                                string[] addresses = (string[])mo["IPAddress"];

                                string IPConnectionMetric = Convert.ToString(mo["IPConnectionMetric"]).Trim();

                                foreach (string ipaddress in addresses)
                                {

                                    listBox1.Items.Add(ipaddress + ";" + IPConnectionMetric);
                                }

                            }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 1)
                {     
                    int maximum = int.MinValue;
                    int minimum = int.MaxValue;
                    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)

                  {
                        int output = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Split(';')[1]);
                        if ((int)output > maximum)
                            maximum = (int)output;

                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int output = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Split(';')[1]);
                        if ((int)output < maximum)
                            minimum = (int)output;

                        if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(minimum.ToString()))
                        {       
                            var minmetric = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();

                            NetworkInterface[] ifConfig = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
                            int maxHash = int.MinValue;
                            Guid D = Guid.Empty;
                            foreach (NetworkInterface net in ifConfig)
                            {
                                if (net.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                                {
                                    if (maxHash < net.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString().GetHashCode())
                                    {
                                        maxHash = net.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString().GetHashCode();

                                        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in net.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                                        {

                                            if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                                            {

                                                if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                                                {
                                                    if (ip.Address.ToString().Contains(minmetric.ToString().Split(';')[0]))
                                                    {
                                                        var ID = new Guid(String.Concat("00000000-0000-0000-0000-", net.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()));
                                                    }
                                                }
            else
                {

                    NetworkInterface[] ifConfig = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
                    int maxHash = int.MinValue;
                    Guid D = Guid.Empty;

                    foreach (NetworkInterface net in ifConfig)
                    {
                        if (net.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                        {
                            if (maxHash < net.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString().GetHashCode())
                            {
                                maxHash = net.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString().GetHashCode();

                                var ID = new Guid(String.Concat("00000000-0000-0000-0000-", net.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()));

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using system.Management;
private string GetMACAddress()
    {
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        string MACAddress = String.Empty;
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if (MACAddress == String.Empty)  // only return MAC Address from first card  
            {
                if ((bool)mo["IPEnabled"] == true) MACAddress = mo["MacAddress"].ToString();
            }
            mo.Dispose();
        }
        MACAddress = MACAddress.Replace(":", "");
        return MACAddress;
    }
```